# When will a dll with singleton class used in another dll be destroyed

Tags: c#, .net, dll

If we create a singleton class in a dll and use it in another dll which instantiates this singleton class, and an exe uses this dll at a point of time, will these two dlls get unloaded immediately after their job or will they get unloaded only when the main exe exits?

Comment: What do you mean by "after their job"?

Comment: Depends on the implementation.  If it's a static singleton, it lasts as long as the AppDomain, or until it gets nulled out.  Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: "dlls get unloaded" No. AppDomains are particularly good at not unloading assemblies. Ever.

Comment: And what do you mean by "destroyed"?

Comment: Hi Skeet , good to see you responding to your student , learned csharp through your videos from pluralsight. you really teach very well. After the job mean when the specific function related to dll gets executed does those two unload automatically or will they be in memory space

Comment: @DStanley by destroyed mean getting unloaded from the user space

Comment: @All my understanding about dll unloading is whenever a exe calls a dll and finishes its job with that dll (mean the routine in the dll gets executed ) it gets unloaded from the memory till a next reference is made , correct me if it is wrong. and in general is it good to have a singleton class in dll

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*Disclaimer*: I am not an expert on memory or processes/app domains, so I may have some specifics wrong, but I firmly believe that my conclusion is valid - feel free to comment and correct any specific errors.</sub>

---

No, the DLL is not unloaded until the app domain that contains it (typically the main process for windows/console apps and the web site for ASP.NET apps) is closed.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101.aspx):

> There is no way to unload an individual assembly without unloading all of the application domains that contain it.

So you *can* manually create (and destroy) app domains, which will unload any DLLs, but then you have to marshal data across the domain boundaries, which may be *worse* than just keeping the DLL in memory.

The *objects* created by the DLL may be removed from memory (if nothing holds a reference to them), but the *code* itself will remain in memory.  In the case of a pure singleton, it will stay in memory until the app closes (since the class that manages it will always have a reference).  You *could* remove the reference to the singleton from the factory class, but you still may have other code that references it, so you risk having *multiple* instances of your "singleton".  If that's not a concern, that may be a valid strategy to dispose of the singleton when you're done with it.

Think about most apps - they respond to human interaction in some way.  Users can click any button, select any menu item, etc. in any order that the app allows. How is an application supposed to know for certain that code within a DLL will never get called again?  Assemblies are relatively expensive to load (in part since they must be JITted), so it would be inefficient to unload them if there's any chance that they'll get loaded again.

**Bottom line** - since the memory footprint of a DLL is usually relatively small (since it just contains code and metadata) and is only loaded once for an entire domain, unless you experience significant memory pressure from it that can't me relived by managing *other* memory better, **I wouldn't go to the trouble of trying to unload it**.